# Why am I damaging animals when I shear/breed them?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I hold shears, face a sheep, and tap the button at the bottom of the screen. The sheep will take damage about 50% of the time. Otherwise, it will work fine.

I am careful that the button is not on the sheep but the crosshairs are.

I have tried 3rd person mode.

I have this problem with breeding any animals too.

Why does this happen and **how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To correctly shear sheep you need to aim at them with shears and *hold* instead of tap. The process is similar to mining with a pickax in that you don't just tap to mine a block.

After tapping and *holding* while aiming at a sheep, it takes about one second for the wool to come off and fall to the ground, so it doesn't take nearly as long as mining does.